# Grubbs, Wittig & hydroboration reactions and Woodward-Hoffmann rules

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, pericyclic

Several organic mechanisms I know involve [2+2] cycloadditions and retro-[2+2] cycloadditions, namely:

- The Wittig reaction
- Hydroboration of an alkene
- Olefin metathesis (using Grubbs' catalyst)

How are these in accordance with the Woodward–Hoffmann rules? I think that there are two $(4q+2)_s$ components and that's not an odd number, which is the criterion for a reaction to be thermally allowed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olefin_metathesis#Reaction_mechanism

Comment: So it happens, regardless of the forbidden symmetry.

Comment: The Woodward-Hoffmann rules for pericylic reactions assumes essentially that you can describe the orbitals in terms of Huckel approximations, which is definitely not the case for a Ru catalyst.

Comment: Could you elaborate as an answer?

Comment: I found an answer in Ahn.N.T "Frontier Orbitals" for hydroboration: "The transition state for a Woodward–Hoffmann-
allowed reaction is aromatic in character, whereas a forbidden one is antiaromatic.
However, the rules of aromaticity only apply when each atom of the annulene uses
one, and only one, AO to bind to its neighbors."

Comment: Could someone expand this into an answer?

Comment: I think you can try - don't be afraid :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. Would be good if someone could expand the answer to account for the Wittig and Grubbs reaction. Wittig may go through a betaine intermediate, but what about Grubbs?

Comment: [Same question but specifically on the Wittig](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/symmetry-forbidden-cycloaddition-in-the-wittig-reaction)