# Symmetry forbidden cycloaddition in the Wittig reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic

My textbook (Klein) describes the mechanism for the Wittig reaction as a [2+2] cycloaddition, followed by a collapse of the ring.

[image]

As far as I'm aware, [2+2] cycloadditions are symmetry forbidden, unless the reaction is light-initiated, which the text does not mention. Is the book wrong? If not, what is going on here?

Comment: What if the reaction is not concerted? ;)

Comment: Then the reaction is not a cycloaddition and a completely different mechanism is needed? (I learned that pericyclic reactions are always concerted, but I may be wrong...)

Comment: Very interesting question! I'd like to point out that a thermal $[2_\mathrm{s} + 2_\mathrm{s}]$ cycloaddition is Woodward-Hoffmann forbidden, but a $[2_\mathrm{s} + 2_\mathrm{a}]$ cycloaddition is (e.g. the reaction of a ketene with an alkene proceeds in this manner). See: [Why is the Wittig reaction syn stereoselective?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5313) Also, Grossman talks about this a bit in his book *The Art of Writing Reasonable Reaction Mechanisms*. I've attached the relevant pages [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0GATVY1ly6cSVBsamxUMUpWbk0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The other question to ask is: what is the symmetry of the orbitals on the phosphorus ylide?

Comment: I think, the simplest explanation here is that the reaction is not concerted. But then remember that the Wittig ylide is not exactly identical to your average alkene either.

Comment: There's some evidence that it's not concerted, but far more evidence that it is. At least, that's what I gather from nearly every org chem textbook I've read. March in particular has references to primary literature.

Comment: @roymend, as for your earlier comment, all pericyclic reactions are indeed concerted. However not all cycloadditions are concerted, and therefore not all cycloadditions are pericyclic. In this case, the others are hinting that a 2-step cycloaddition can exist, and it would be neither pericyclic nor concerted.

Comment: For a somewhat recent review of the mechanism of the Wittig reaction proposed in the past, have a look at *Chem. Soc. Rev.*, **2013**, *16*, 6670-6696 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c3cs60105f))